# Customer markers with html5 don't locate over position

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, html5-canvas

I am working with a static image that I have rotated using canvas on HTML5, however when I have gotten the result, cause of the form of the image, it is not on the right position. It is a little high.

I need a way to solve this issue in order get my car positioned correctly over the street. How I could do it?

**Original image**

[image]

**Redrawed image is**

[image: marker sample]

**Sample map after rotate the image**

[image: Map sample]

**Code used**

```
function callbackIconMarkerSuccess (index, urlIconMarker) {
    markers[index].setIcon(urlIconMarker);
}
function setIconMarker(index, course, speed){
    course = parseFloat (course) * 0.01745327777;
    if (parseInt(speed) > 5) {
        imageIcon = '{% static "markers/icon_max.png" %}';
    } else {
        imageIcon = '{% static "markers/onstop.png" %}';
    }
    var elemento = document.createElement("canvas");
    if(elemento && elemento.getContext){
        var context = elemento.getContext('2d');
        if(context){
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = imageIcon;
            imageObj.onload = function(){
                elemento.width = imageObj.width;
                elemento.height = imageObj.height;
                context.save();
                context.translate(imageObj.width/2, imageObj.height/2);
                context.rotate(course);
                context.drawImage(imageObj, -(imageObj.width/2), -(imageObj.height/2));
                //context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
                //context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
                //context.fillStyle="#550000";
                context.fillRect(imageObj.width/2, imageObj.height/2, elemento.width,elemento.height);
                context.restore();
                callbackIconMarkerSuccess(index, elemento.toDataURL());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not show the actual creation of the Marker, but assuming you're using a [`google.maps.Icon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) you probably want to look at the [`anchor`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) property:

> The position at which to anchor an image in correspondance to the location of the marker on the map. By default, the anchor is located along the center point of the bottom of the image.

Comment: As you could see at the first lines of the code, the Icon Image ise set with the method setIcon, and yes I was looking the way on anchor the image. Thanks

Comment: An oversight on my part, but I'm glad my answer helped regardless.